# Split a numeric ID column into two using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

```
              DateTime  Junction  Vehicles           ID
0  2015-11-01 00:00:00         1        15  20151101001
1  2015-11-01 01:00:00         1        13  20151101011
2  2015-11-01 02:00:00         1        10  20151101021
3  2015-11-01 03:00:00         1         7  20151101031
4  2015-11-01 04:00:00         1         9  20151101041
5  2015-11-01 05:00:00         1         6  20151101051
6  2015-11-01 06:00:00         1         9  20151101061
7  2015-11-01 07:00:00         1         8  20151101071
8  2015-11-01 08:00:00         1        11  20151101081
9  2015-11-01 09:00:00         1        12  20151101091
```

I want to split the `ID` column into two separate columns such that the first 4 digits are in one, and the remaining digits are in the second.

Code I've tried:

```
new_ID = data.apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(4))
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do this with pandas?

Comment: Also, this is a trivially simple problem. You better show about 5-10 rows of your data, along with expected output and the code you've tried that presumably doesn't work.

Comment: Also, there's a pandas tag, use it. The other tags are irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: No, not as pictures. As _text_.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm relatively new here, I'm unable to add table. I've used .str.rsplit() but in vain.

Comment: Just `print(df.head(10))`, paste it here, highlight, and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: I understand what you want, but I want to make sure your question ticks all the boxes before answering it.

Comment: Good, we're getting somewhere. Post any relevant code you've tried, and we're good to go.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was trying to separate year from the ID column

Comment: Okay, that helps, and is useful information. Post your code, if you have any. Expected output is a bonus, but I've already understood, so it isn't necessary.

Comment: new_ID= data.apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(4))

Comment: Look at your question now. Keep this in mind for future reference, this is how an appropriate question for Stack Overflow looks like.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Noted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
The simplest and most direct - use the `str` accessor.

```
v = df.ID.astype(str)
df['Year'], df['ID'] = v.str[:4], v.str[4:]

df

              DateTime  Junction  Vehicles       ID  Year
0 2015-11-01  00:00:00         1        15  1101001  2015
1 2015-11-01  01:00:00         1        13  1101011  2015
2 2015-11-01  02:00:00         1        10  1101021  2015
3 2015-11-01  03:00:00         1         7  1101031  2015
4 2015-11-01  04:00:00         1         9  1101041  2015
5 2015-11-01  05:00:00         1         6  1101051  2015
6 2015-11-01  06:00:00         1         9  1101061  2015
7 2015-11-01  07:00:00         1         8  1101071  2015
8 2015-11-01  08:00:00         1        11  1101081  2015
9 2015-11-01  09:00:00         1        12  1101091  2015
```

---

**Option 2**
`str.extract`

```
v = df.ID.astype(str).str.extract('(?P<Year>\d{4})(?P<ID>.*)', expand=True)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('ID', 1), v], 1)

df

              DateTime  Junction  Vehicles  Year       ID
0 2015-11-01  00:00:00         1        15  2015  1101001
1 2015-11-01  01:00:00         1        13  2015  1101011
2 2015-11-01  02:00:00         1        10  2015  1101021
3 2015-11-01  03:00:00         1         7  2015  1101031
4 2015-11-01  04:00:00         1         9  2015  1101041
5 2015-11-01  05:00:00         1         6  2015  1101051
6 2015-11-01  06:00:00         1         9  2015  1101061
7 2015-11-01  07:00:00         1         8  2015  1101071
8 2015-11-01  08:00:00         1        11  2015  1101081
9 2015-11-01  09:00:00         1        12  2015  1101091
```

Comment: @chdeepak See option one and modify as you wish.

Comment: I think first solution is best, +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a numeric solution (assuming that the length of `ID` column is constant):

```
In [10]: df['Year'], df['ID'] = df['ID'] // 10**7, df['ID'] % 10**7

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
              DateTime  Junction  Vehicles       ID  Year
0 2015-11-01  00:00:00         1        15  1101001  2015
1 2015-11-01  01:00:00         1        13  1101011  2015
2 2015-11-01  02:00:00         1        10  1101021  2015
3 2015-11-01  03:00:00         1         7  1101031  2015
4 2015-11-01  04:00:00         1         9  1101041  2015
5 2015-11-01  05:00:00         1         6  1101051  2015
6 2015-11-01  06:00:00         1         9  1101061  2015
7 2015-11-01  07:00:00         1         8  1101071  2015
8 2015-11-01  08:00:00         1        11  1101081  2015
9 2015-11-01  09:00:00         1        12  1101091  2015
```

Comment: Nice, retains numeric property too.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thank you! You solution is much more generic!

Answer (score -1):

```
df[id_col].map(lambda x: int(str(x)[:5])) # as an integer
df[id_col].map(lambda x: str(x)[:5]) # as a string
```